# Does CacheStorage (Web Cache) API care about headers like Content-Encoding?

Tags: javascript, http, web, webapi, deno

I am using the newly added [CacheStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) API in [Deno 1.26](https://deno.com/blog/v1.26). My understanding is that this basically functions as a `Map<Request, Response>`. I question what aspects of the `Request` object factor into determining whether or not it's a match. For instance, is only the URL taken into account? I began to think about what would happen if a request came in for a particular URL with `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br` and then the response contained a gzip compressed body with header `Content-Encoding: gzip`. What then would happen if the same URL was requested by a client whose request contains e.g. `Accept-Encoding: deflate`. Would the CacheStorage API match this based off the URL alone and return the response with the gziped body?

Well I tested this scenario in Deno and it appears to be the case. Deno appears to only match based off the URL and doesn't care about the `Content-Encoding` header. So my question is whether this is a bug in Deno's implementation or whether or not its simply an oversite in the web API. Perhaps I'm overthinking this and in reality its moot because virtualy all HTTP clients in use today support gzip compressed responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only header considered in the [`Request` matches cached item algorithm](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#request-matches-cached-item-algorithm) is the `Vary` header.

External clients don't call the `Cache` API itself. Your application code is able to manage those calls completely.

Here are some ideas on making an application that uses the `Cache` API and supports both compressed and uncompressed responses to its clients:

- internally use a specific compression with the `Cache` API
- require clients to support the encoding or add support for on-demand decompression (see next item)
- when serving a `Response` from the `Cache` to a client…

  - if the client specifies that it accepts the same encoding then return the compressed response directly from the `Cache`
  - if the client specifies that it accepts other encodings but not the one your application is using internally then decompress and possibly re-compress using a different algorithm to return the desired `Response`
  - if the client specifies no encodings that it accepts then decompress the `Response` from `Cache` to return to the client